# Jdbc Feeder using data created in simulation before step

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to make a feeder that is based on jdbc data that is being created in the before step of a scenario. I do not manage to get the correct data in the feeder.

```scala
package com.testing

import com.testing.config.Config
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef.Simulation
import io.gatling.core.feeder.SourceFeederBuilder
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef.jdbcFeeder

object PostgresDb {

  def prepareData() {
   // postgress data generation here
  }

  def emptyDatabase() {
   // postgress truncate table
  }
}

class MyFeeder {
  private[this] val databaseConfig: Config.DatabaseConfig = Config.databaseConfig

  // Database feeder
  val dbData : SourceFeederBuilder[Any]
  = jdbcFeeder( databaseConfig.url
    , databaseConfig.username
    , databaseConfig.password
    , "SELECT \"Id\" FROM test.\"Ids\" ORDER BY random()"
  ).circular
}


class Experiment extends Simulation {

  before{ PostgresDb.emptyDatabase()
          PostgresDb.prepareData() }

  val lazyFeeder = new MyFeeder

  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")

  val scn = scenario("Demo").feed(lazyFeeder.dbData).
            exec(session => {
                    println("Id: " + session("Id").as[String])
                    session }).inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  setUp(scn)

}
```

I would expect to have data in my feeder based on the prepare/before step of my scenario. However I seem to get data of my previous run which implies the feeder data is being initialised before the data is renewed in the before step.

How can I use the fresh data and not the data that is in the database already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you define the feeder where it currently is, but initialise it in the 'before' block, it should work.

at the moment, you're initialising and running the feeder query at the time your class is loaded - which is before anything (including the before block) has been executed.

Comment: Thanks for helping James!
I tried to move the jdbcFeeder(..) within the before block but without luck.
Can you elaborate you answer with an example?

Comment: Got it to work. Moved the postgresDb function calls outside the before block (removed it) and then initialised the feeder.

Comment: @Pigna Can you please share the code on how you got it to work? In my case I need to first create some users by calling an api and write it to a file and then run the scenario that uses a feeder pointing to the file with users. The error I get is feeder is empty.